# Impulse Response for Single Equation model

Tags: impulse-response

Can an impulse response be generated for a single equation model? For instance, can an impulse response be generated for an AR(p), and ARDL, or MS(m)-AR(p) models.
I have seen the following link, but I am uncertain if an impulse response can be generated for a single equation model since I though it could only be done for a system.
http://www.alexchinco.com/impulse-response-functions-for-vars/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, impulse-response can be generated for single equation models. In fact, it is a convenient tool for understanding the dynamics of a time series described by an ARMA model, for example. Impulse-response for AR, ARDL and Markov switching AR would also work.